# How to fill html table made grid with colors using mouse click?

Tags: javascript, html, interface

I want to create a simple tool so that user can fill colors inside html table fields or whatever the alternative you can suggest.
Take a look at this page:
http://www.olmares.com/Price%20and%20Availability.htm

I am looking for some tool, interface, Javascript or any other way so that my client fill in the table boxes with colors easily. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added an extra, so when you click on highlighted td, it will remove it.

Working link : http://jsfiddle.net/dEy2H/

**CSS**

```
.HighLight {background-color:#ff0000 !important;}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $('td').click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('HighLight'))
            $(this).removeClass('HighLight');
        else
            $(this).addClass('HighLight');
    });
});
```

Comment: I want like when i start clicking a green cell then from that all other rows where my mouse moves with clicking so ideally its is dragging should be turn to red. same way in red to green. can you tell me how can i do that ?

Comment: That's a different question - please create a new question where we can answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can set csscalass for your table td by javascript.

```
    <Table><tr>
<td cssclass="a"></td><td cssclass="b"></td>
</tr></table>
```

and your css:

```
.a{backgroundcolor:red}
.b{backgroundcolor:green}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set up a click handler for your table cells that react by changing the color of the cell clicked in .. in jQuery it'd be something like

```
var current_color = 'red';

$('td').click(function() {
   $(this).css('background-color', current_color);
});
```

thus whatever the current_color is (changed perhaps via other user interaction) gets applied to subsequently clicked cells.